# Installing rasterio python package

Tags: python, gdal, installation, rasterio, anaconda

I am trying to install 'rasterio' package in my conda environment. It is throwing below error

```
Collecting rasterio
  Using cached rasterio-1.2.10.tar.gz (2.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      INFO:root:Building on Windows requires extra options to setup.py to locate needed GDAL files. More information is available in the README.
      ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

So I installed GDAL from [here](https://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1930-x64-gdal-3-5-3-mapserver-8-0-0.zip). Below is where it got saved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KonsI.png)

Now, I re-ran the installation command, and still facing the same issue. I think it is regarding the setting the environment variables.

What should I set the variables as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to install 'rasterio' package in my **conda** environment.

For conda environments, use `conda` to [install packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

conda install -c conda-forge rasterio